# Register a MAPI message service for a non-priviliged user

Tags: outlook, mapi

How to register a MAPI service provider for the user without admin privileges? I found the mapisvc.inf file only in the system folders.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook will also check mapisvc.inf in `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA\Microsoft\Outlook\mapisvc.inf` (e.g. `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\mapisvc.inf`).
The file will be deleted by Outlook after it picks up your provider.

You will also need to create a `REG_DWORD` value named `EnableUnregisteredMapiProviders` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>.0\Outlook\Security` and set its value to 1.

Comment: I've create the mapisvc.inf in 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook' and create EnableUnregisteredMapiProviders in 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security and set its value to 1. Unfortunately the behavior doesn't change.
Would you help me please to solve that problem?

Comment: When Outlook later runs, does it delete the inf file? Have you tried to use Process Monitor to see if it touches the file and the registry value?

Comment: Outlook deletes the inf file from AppData. (SetDispositionInformationFile C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\mapisvc.inf SUCCESS Delete: True). There is no events in procmon for reading registry value by key like EnableUnregisteredMapiProviders (EnableUnregisteredMapiServices, AllowUnregisteredMapiProviders,AllowUnregisteredMapiServices).

Comment: P. S. outlook version is "Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11328.20156), 64-bit".

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know. Is opening a support case with MS an option?

Comment: I found that "AllowUnregisteredMapiServices" only works in Outlook 2007. But Outlook 2007 does not read the mapisvc.inf file from AppData.

Comment: Yes, you need to use EnableUnregisteredMapiProviders in the latest versions of Outlook.